# Not able to filter data from csv sheet according to user input in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample csv sheet that looks something  like this

```
  Start Time         End Time       Trip Duration    Start Station   End Station 
  01/01/17 15:09    01/01/17 15:14     321           A               B
  01/02/17 15:09    01/02/17 15:14     321           C               D
  12/03/17 15:09    12/03/17 15:14     321           E               F
  05/01/17 15:09    05/01/17 15:14     321           B               D
  17/02/17 15:09    17/02/17 15:14     321           C               F
  12/04/17 15:09    12/04/17 15:14     321           E               H
  13/05/17 15:09    13/05/17 15:14     321           S               K
  17/01/17 15:09    17/01/17 15:14     321           A               D
```

I am able to read the above file and get the values of month and day using the following code

```
df = pd.read_csv(sample.csv)
df['month'] = df['Start Time'].dt.month
df['day_of_week'] = df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name
```

But I have a requirement where the user is asked to enter month or day, then according to those values entered by the user a new data needs to be created over which further actions will be done.

E.g: If the user enters **January** then the where ever the month is January in Start Time, **data related to that is displayed**. The new data should be something like this

```
  Start Time         End Time       Trip Duration    Start Station   End Station 
 01/01/17 15:09   01/01/17 15:14       321           A               B
 05/01/17 15:09   05/01/17 15:14       321           B               D
 17/01/17 15:09   17/01/17 15:14       321           A               D
```

AND if the user enters a day, eg **Monday** (**lets assume for monday the date is 12**), then the o/p should be something like this

```
  Start Time         End Time       Trip Duration    Start Station   End Station 
12/03/17 15:09     12/03/17 15:14      321           E               F
12/04/17 15:09     12/04/17 15:14      321           E               H
```

Then on these new tables furtur actions/calculations are need to be done.

Can anyone please tell how this new filtered data can be created

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the `calendar` module to get a list of and month and day of week names, then use a simple `if else` syntax to filter your dataframe by user input:

```
import calendar

# Start by converting start time to proper datetime format:
df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])

months = list(calendar.month_name)
days = list(calendar.day_name)

user_in = input('What do you want to filter by? ')

if user_in in months:
    filtered = df[df['Start Time'].dt.strftime('%B').eq(user_in)]
elif user_in in days:
    filtered = df[df['Start Time'].dt.strftime('%A').eq(user_in)]
else:
    print('Invalid Input')
```

Say `user_in` is January, then the `filtered` dataframe looks like:

```
>>> filtered
           Start Time        End Time  Trip Duration Start Station End Station
0 2017-01-01 15:09:00  01/01/17 15:14            321             A           B
1 2017-01-02 15:09:00  01/02/17 15:14            321             C           D
7 2017-01-17 15:09:00  17/01/17 15:14            321             A           D
```

And if `user_in` is Monday:

```
>>> filtered
           Start Time        End Time  Trip Duration Start Station End Station
1 2017-01-02 15:09:00  01/02/17 15:14            321             C           D
3 2017-05-01 15:09:00  05/01/17 15:14            321             B           D
5 2017-12-04 15:09:00  12/04/17 15:14            321             E           H
```